# Use child method from parent class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, subclass

**classes.php**

```
class System {

    protected $domain;

    public function __construct($domain) {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

}

class Subsystem extends System {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getDomain() {
        echo $this->domain;
    }

 }
```

**index.php**

```
require('classes.php');

$system = new System('http://google.com');
$system->getDomain();
```

I recently decided to move from procedural to object-oriented PHP, but I'm having an issue understanding the concepts of inheritance.
Why doesn't the above code work? The page returns this error: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method System::getDomain()**

Comment: `System` class knows __nothing__ about child classes' methods.

Comment: So it is not possible to use a child method from a parent class?

Comment: Instantiate `Subsystem` not `System`. Child knows its parent but not vice versa

Comment: Absolutlely impossible.

Comment: Okay. thank you, will try that. Feel free to write an answer so I can mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is not working like this.

Your class System only has it's own methods and attributes available when creating an instance. While your Class SubSystem will have all of its own and its parents (System).

For more information take a look at the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php